# PHP not retrieving new data until page refresh

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

What is happening is I think my code is selecting the data first (basically old data) then updating it but what I want is for it to update then select the data (new data). How can I do this?

I am going to post where it goes wrong and if you need the full code just ask:

```
        $select_links = $db->query("SELECT pid, added_by,link_title,lid,link_order FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "homepage_links WHERE pid='$pid' 
         ORDER BY link_order DESC LIMIT $start,$show");
    $check_link_count_rows = $db->num_rows($select_links);
    echo "<b> You Current Have " . $check_link_count_rows . " Links On Your Page: </b><br>";
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
";
    while($select_links_array = $db->fetch_array($select_links)) {
    $link_title_display = $select_links_array['link_title'];
    $link_id_display = $select_links_array['lid'];
    if(!$mybb->input["order_edit_$link_id_display"]) {
    $link_order_display = $select_links_array['link_order'];
    } else {
    $link_order_display = $mybb->input["order_edit_$link_id_display"];
    }



    $order_edit_value1 = $mybb->input["order_edit_$link_id_display"];
    $order_edit_value = $db->escape_string($order_edit_value1);


    echo "<br>" . $link_title_display . " <a href='?operation=edit_links&link=$link_id_display'> (edit) </a>

    <input type='number' name='order_edit_$link_id_display' value='$link_order_display' style='width:40px;'>
    <input type='hidden' name='get_link_id_display_value_$link_id_display' value='$link_id_display'><br>

    ";



$get_link_id_display_value1 =  $mybb->input["get_link_id_display_value_$link_id_display"];
$get_link_id_display_value = $db->escape_string($get_link_id_display_value1);
    $update_quick_edit_query = $db->query("UPDATE spud_homepage_links SET link_order='$order_edit_value'
WHERE lid='$get_link_id_display_value'");
    }
```

I cannot find a solution as everything is in the right place for it to work besides this bug.

Comment: It does look like your `UPDATE` is at the end. Have you tried moving that part of the logic before the `SELECT` that reads the data?

Comment: Yes that's what i'm trying to do but since I am looping through fields in a while loop then getting values for the update to work I can't which complicates things as you can't even go before the while loop values and input post fields :/ and thanks for a reply! hoping to solve this

Comment: Ah, if the first `SELECT` is required to set up data for the `UPDATE`, then just run another `SELECT` at the end before you render the screen. Are you doing the update in response to a form submission? What is its purpose?

Comment: The purpose for the select is both it also fetches the data and I can try and see how that goes :) but might screw how things are displayed but thanks for the help and advice :)

Comment: No, what is the purpose of the **update**? Is it for a form submission?

Comment: oh you mean the update what I have is a list of links and i'm allowing the user set the order so that's why it's looping through with the while loop so once they specify a order number for each field and click submit it will update the order number so that's what the update is for you can say it's "form submission" 
hope this explains the basic functionality

Comment: Right, so you are doing this update in response to a form. You're doing in wrong, I think - after the update you should redirect to the page containing the amended data. You can use `header('Location: ')` for that. Your form uses a `POST` method, I trust?

Comment: Read this: http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/get-redirect-after-post

Comment: Yes ;)
I though about just slowing down the load time to give it a chance to update after all PHP should find a executing fix
If I do decide to use header(Location:') would that make me prone to any XXS attacks or slow down the site performance if 500 or more users are using the application just double checking and thanks heaps so far :)

Comment: "would that make me prone to any [XSS] attacks or slow down the performance" - no.

Comment: ok will I have tried and it worked fine :D issue fixed!
Thanks if there is anyway I can repay you I be able to as long as it's nothing too big ;)

Comment: Done :) and thanks loads again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a discussion in the comments, I determined that you were attempting to render a page after a `post` form submission that amends the database. It is perfectly possible to re-read your new database state and render it in a post operation, but it is inadvisable, since browsers cannot refresh the page without asking you if you wish to run the operation again. This does not make for a good user experience, especially in relation to using the back/forward buttons.

The reason for this behaviour is that post operations generally modify the database. They are used for example in credit card purchases or profile amendments where some change in the state of the server is expected. Thus, it is good practice to execute a new round-trip to the server, after the write operation, to change the page method from `post` to `get`.

The `header()` call I linked to will do this, and will resolve your rendering problem too.